# Couchbase load one bucket ˜40k documents causing slowness

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I’m using CB Lite 1.4 in an android application. I’ve a bucket with ~40k documents and would like to export the bucket by parts or filter it.  My problem is loading 40k at a time is causing a slowness in the application.

I’m use sync gateway.

Comment: Is the slowness in your android application? How would you like to filter?

Comment: @MatthewGroves yes slowness in my application. I would like it to load only the first 100 records and then when the user loads the timeline he would load the other records.

Comment: are you doing anything with channels? https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/2.1/data-routing.html

Comment: @MatthewGroves Yes, I use channels, but I'm using a channel.
    `    Replication puller = database.createPullReplication(replicationURL);
         puller.setAuthenticator(this.auth);
         puller.setContinuous(true);
         List<String> channels = new ArrayList<String>();
         channels.add("timeline");
         puller.setChannels(channels);`

Comment: We kinda need a real question, here.  40k is a lot of documents.  Moving them is bound to be slow.  Channels are a great way of parcelling them into bite-sized pieces.  If channels won't work of you, you'll need some other way of doing that.

Comment: I was trying to make changes only in the android application and really had no way, I managed to filter my database and create a new channel, which will store the first 100 posts, loading the rest in the background. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DiogoMoura Cool!  Please consider writing a Medium article about how you did it.